# Не отображается содержимое таблицы DataTable Yajra Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

Попытался реализовать таблицу. Заглавие столбцов выводятся, но самих данных нету. Никаких ошибок тоже не выводится.
Также не выводятся стандартные кнопки Datatable. Все виджеты Datatable не отображаются(поиск и т.д.). Вроде бы все, что нужно, в html файле подключил. В чем может быть проблема. Ниже представил все файлы(их отрывки), которые имеют отношение.

app.php

```
'providers' => [

    \Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider::class,

],

'aliases' => [

    'DataTables' => \Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables::class,
],
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/service/format', [\App\Http\Controllers\FormatController::class, 'index'])->name('service.format.index');
```

Модель Format.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Format extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'formats';

    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Контроллер FomatController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DataTables\FormatDataTable;

class FormatController extends Controller
{
    public function index(FormatDataTable $dataTable){
        return $dataTable->render('service.format.index');
    }
}
```

Файл таблицы FormatDataTable.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\Models\Format;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Button;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Column;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Editor;
use Yajra\DataTables\Html\Editor\Fields;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class FormatDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables()
            ->eloquent($query)
            ->addColumn('action', 'format.action');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Format $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(Format $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery();
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
                    ->setTableId('format-table')
                    ->columns($this->getColumns())
                    ->minifiedAjax()
                    ->dom('Bfrtip')
                    ->orderBy(1)
                    ->buttons(
                        Button::make('create'),
                        Button::make('export'),
                        Button::make('print'),
                        Button::make('reset'),
                        Button::make('reload')
                    );
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            Column::computed('action')
                  ->exportable(false)
                  ->printable(false)
                  ->width(60)
                  ->addClass('text-center'),
            Column::make('id'),
            Column::make('name'),
            Column::make('created_at'),
            Column::make('updated_at'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'Format_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

Вьюха index.blade.php

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Форматы документа</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></scrippt>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></scrippt>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section style="padding-top: 60px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                {!! $dataTable->table() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{!! $dataTable->scripts() !!}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Там вроде для того чтобы были Buttons, нужно дополнительный пакет ставить https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons

Comment: Собственно более подробно об этом https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/buttons-installation

Comment: @Simon да не, я нашел ошибку, у меня там скрипты подключаются неверно scrippt написано=(

Comment: Исправил, мб понадобится кому-то=)